# Creating a histogram with C++ (Homework)

Tags: c++, formatting, histogram

In my c++ class, we got assigned pairs.  Normally I can come up with an effective algorithm quite easily, this time I cannot figure out how to do this to save my life.

What I am looking for is someone to explain an algorithm (or just give me tips on what would work) in order to get this done. I'm still at the planning stage and want to get this code done on my own in order to learn. I just need a little help to get there.

We have to create histograms based on a 4 or 5 integer input. It is supposed to look something like this:

```
Calling histo(5, 4, 6, 2) should produce output that appears like:

        *
    *   *
    * * *
    * * *
    * * * *
    * * * *
    -------
    A B C D
```

The formatting to this is just killing me. What makes it worse is that we **cannot** use any type of arrays or "advanced" sorting systems using other libraries.

At first I thought I could arrange the values from highest to lowest order. But then I realized I did not know how to do this without using the sort function and I was not sure how to go on from there.

Kudos for anyone who could help me get started on this assignment. :)

Comment: Do you mean you want to print that to the console... or what?

Comment: If you wanted to sort (for whatever reason) I'd look up how to do a "bubble sort" manually. It's useful to know about that anyway.

Comment: @Pluckerpluck, Isn't quicksort the way to go though?

Comment: It looks like it's just a formatting puzzle. Instead of looking at it up and down, how about looking at it left to right?

Comment: I would prefer a quicksort, but I was giving the option for a simpler approach before he looks into optimisations. And what is more simple that a bubble sort.

Comment: But yes, look left to right and at each location compare with your number to see if you should print a asterix at that height.

Comment: Why even sort at all? How is it required when all the data is given, and you don't need to order anything

Comment: He has to print one histogram of four variables... there's no harm in a bubble sort at that level (especially when learning). But yes, don't order these variables, there's no need as you print line by line.

Comment: Lol, I'm a girl. Yes. I want it to be printed to the console. Okay. I won't order these, it was just an idea. At this point, I have been trying all ideas.

Comment: Your professor is probably telling you you can't sort / use arrays to not confuse you, as they aren't required at all.

Comment: Alright. That could be it. Thank you guys/girls for all your help. I believe I can do it from this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along the lines of this:

1. Determine the largest number in the histogram
2. Using a loop like this to construct the histogram:

   `for(int i = largest; i >= 1; i--)`

   Inside the body of the loop, do steps 3 to 5 inclusive
3. If `i <= value_of_column_a` then print a `*`, otherwise print a space
4. Repeat step 3 for each column (or write a loop...)
5. Print a newline character
6. Print the horizontal line using `-`
7. Print the column labels

Comment: Woah. Why did I not think of this? The way you are putting it, sounds so easy. I'm going to start coding this and see if it works, but I think it will. Thank you.

Comment: @Lindsiria, probably stress clouded your thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm mistaken on your q, but if you know how many items are in each column, it should be pretty easy to print them like your example:

Step 1: Find the Max of the numbers, store in variable, assign to column.

Step 2: Print spaces until you get to column with the max. Print star. Print remaining stars / spaces. Add a \n character.

Step 3: Find next max. Print stars in columns where the max is >= the max, otherwise print a space. Add newline. at end.

Step 4: Repeat step 3 (until stop condition below)

when you've printed the # of stars equal to the largest max, you've printed all of them.

Step 5: add the -------- line, and a \n

Step 6: add row headers and a \n

Comment: The user inputs how many columns the graph has (4 or 5) then how many items are in each column. So I don't know offhand the number the user is going to input. This way could work if i modify it.

Comment: @Lindsiria That really shouldn't be any different - but you mention the function being histogr..(5,4,3,2) - therefore, you have 4 columns (A,B,C,D), and their values (A=5,B=4,C=3,D=2)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly I think the problem can be solved like this:

```
a= <array of the numbers entered>
T=<number of numbers entered> = length(a) //This variable is used to 
                                          //determine if we have finished
                                          //and it will change its value

Alph={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,..., Z}  //A constant array containing the alphabet
                             //We will use it to print the bottom row

for (i=1 to T) {print Alph[i]+" "}; //Prints the letters (plus space), 
                                    //one for each number entered

for (i=1 to T) {print "--"};        //Prints the two dashes per letter above 
                                    //the letters, one for each

while (T!=0) do {
   for (i=1 to N) do {
       if (a[i]>0) {print "*"; a[i]--;} else {print " "; T--;};
   };
   if (T!=0) {T=N};

}
```

What this does is, for each non-zero entered number, it will print a * and then decrease the number entered. When one of the numbers becomes zero it stops putting *s for its column. When all numbers have become zero (notice that this will occur when the value of T comes out of the *for* as zero. This is what the variable T is for) then it stops.

I think the problem wasn't really about histograms. Notice it also doesn't require sorting or even knowing the